# Is there any other date **where/when** I can write the exam? When or Where?

Tags: word-choice

Is there any other date where/when I can write the exam?

Should I use when or where in that sentence

Comment: Either one is fine.

Comment: "Where" would be better, to make it clear that you're asking about the date when to take the exam rather than the place. And by the way, if you're a student, we say you "take" or "sit" the exam, not "write the exam".

Comment: @RosieF: did you mean "when"? I can't make sense of the first sentence in your comment.

Comment: @ColinFine Oops, yes, you're right, I did mean "when".

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the people who have commented, I find only "when" to be normal here, as it is a date.

If I heard it with "where", I would assume the speaker was thinking of a 'date' not as a date on the calendar, but a place and time - which makes some sort of sense for an exam, which presumably has assigned places and times. But I would still find it odd.

Answer (score 1):

Only '**when**' makes sense to me, particularly as you specify "date". I mean, I'd know what you meant either way, but "where" would seem wrong - just an understandable sort of wrong.

Also, in English, we say "**sit** an exam" or "**take** an exam", not "write an exam".

Comment: In my (American) experience, I am used to "taking" exams.  I have the impression that some of our fellow contributors from other continents "write" exams.

Comment: No national variant of English that I know of *writes* exams, but I suppose they might in some that I've not come across. If I didn't know it was a common mistranslation (I've come across it before with native speakers of a range of other languages), I would have thought it was a mistaken way of saying they were to *set* an exam.